# Sitecore caching and external data source

Tags: caching, lucene, sitecore, external

I am working on a website where right rail and menu components will be using an external data source exclusively. The external source is a Lucene based index which sits on a different server.

I want to implement Sitecore caching on these components but I want the cache to refresh when new data is available for the component in the index. New data will be available very frequently. I am talking in terms of seconds not minutes or hours in some cases. How can I achieve Sitecore caching in this instance?

I am using Sitecore 6.5 for this website.

Comment: Please refer to this other question about the same topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297180/sitecore-html-cache-and-external-data-sources/6301743#6301743

Comment: Duplicate of this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297180/sitecore-html-cache-and-external-data-sources/6301743#6301743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the duplicate post I mentioned above, if your content is updating so frequently (in seconds) it might not even be worth the caching overhead if you will have an infrequent number of hits per each cache instance. You'll end up using memory for the caches and barely use them. Instead use Lucene.NET to deliver your component a collection of `SkinnyItem` (a very fast operation) and convert them to `Item` at the last moment when binding to the front-end (e.g. an `ItemDataBound` event in a `Repeater`)

Comment: I don't even have the need to go back to Lucene.NET to get item (or skinny item) information from Sitecore. All the information I need resides in this external index.

Comment: If that's the case then you can look up the value from the `SkinnyItem`, e.g. `string yourFieldVal = skinnyItem.Fields["your field"];`